# Error when attempting to retrieve one element using Vuex getter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application, vue-router, vuex

I'm creating a single page app using Vue/Vuex/Vue-router.

Basically I'm trying to retrieve one record after selecting it from a shown list, my store consists of basically:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    reports: null,
    loading: false,
    reportProcessing: false
  },
  getters: {
    getReports (state) {
      return state.reports
    },
    getReport (state) {
      return (id) => {
        return state.reports.find((item) => {
          return item.id === id
        })
      }
    }
  }
  // ...
```

When I try to use it with

```
data () {
  return {
    // Attempt to load the report by passing the current id
    report: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters.getReport(this.id))),
// ...
```

It shows an error for `"SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"` basically returns a null/empty object, which is really confusing because this works (selecting the first element from the object list) :

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters.getReports[0])),
```

So I know the object list contains the reports (and that the getters seem to run properly). It doesn't work however when attempting to pass the id manually like `this.$store.getters.getReport(1)`

Exactly what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT :**
My current router file is set to (for the single report route)

```
{
  path: '/report/:id',
  props: true,
  component: MainLayout,
  children: [
    { path: '', name: 'edit_report', component: EditReport }
  ]
}
```

Basically I'm using vue-router's child routes to load the components inside a layout that has the main menu, however when I removed this function for that route to :

```
{
  path: '/report/:id',
  name: 'edit_report',
  props: true,
  component: EditReport
}
```

It worked (obviously without being loaded inside the main layout), needless to say this isn't a fix (since i still need it to load inside the main layout like all the other pages), but maybe it has some relation to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an `this.id` that does not exist. The `.find()` in the `getReports()` getter will return `undefined` and the `JSON.parse()` will throw that error.

Here's a breakdown of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters.getReport(this.id)))`, with `this.id` equal to `6`:

- `this.$store.getters.getReport(6)` returns `undefined`
- `JSON.stringify(undefined)` returns `undefined`
- `JSON.parse(undefined)` throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` error.

Demo below.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    reports: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}],
    loading: false,
    reportProcessing: false
  },
  getters: {
    getReports (state) {
      return state.reports
    },
    getReport (state) {
      return (id) => {
        return state.reports.find((item) => {
          return item.id === id
        })
      }
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    reports: function() {
      return this.$store.state.reports
    },
  },
  methods: {
    callGetReport() {
      console.log(this.$store.getters.getReport(6));
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters.getReport(6)));
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters.getReport(6))));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.15/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Reports: {{ reports }}</p>
  <button @click="callGetReport">Click here to call getReport() - open browser's console to see result</button>
</div>
```

## Passing props to child (nested) routes

You are not getting the `id` in the nested route because the `props` are not turned on:

```
{
  path: '/report/:id',
  props: true,
  component: MainLayout,
  children: [
    { path: '', name: 'edit_report', component: EditReport, props: true }
                                                       // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ------ added this
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but I'll try. See the edit to the answer.

Comment: Well golly that actually solved it! i had props turned on but i completely forgot that it had to be true on the children route..